# Why is JPA retrieving one column using a seperate select

Tags: java, sql, jpa, openjpa

## Problem description

Hello, I've been using OpenJPA 2.1.2 (JPA 2.0) to retrieve data from a table called `LOGISCHRAPPORT`which has about 28 columns. In some cases OpenJPA decides to issue seperate select statements for one of the columns for no particular reason, leading to a dramatic decrease in query performance.

### Everything is fine until...

Initially everything goes fine and all my columns are retrieved in a performant, single `SELECT` statement by JPA.

As soon as I  add a relationship to another entity called `RAPTAALMETADATA`

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "RAPPORTNR", referencedColumnName = "RAPPORTNR"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "RAPPORTTYPE", referencedColumnName = "RAPPORTTYPE") })
private List<Raptaalmetadata> raptaalmetadata;
--- 
Queried using Criteria API as follows:
---
Join<LogischRapport, Raptaalmetadata> metadata = reportRoot.join(
    "raptaalmetadata");
```

JPA **no longer includes one of my original columns** called `REPORT_COMMENTS` instead it is **issuing separate select statements** to retrieve the `REPORT_COMMENTS` column for each instance of `LOGISCHRAPPORT`. All other columns (including the ones coming from `RAPTAALMETADATA` are retrieved properly as part of the intial SELECT.

`REPORT_COMMENTS` is of the `HUGEBLOB` type in Oracle and I've mapped in in my Entity as follows:

```
@Lob
@Basic
@Column(name = "REPORT_COMMENTS")
private byte[] reportComments;
```

I now get tons of these:

```
SELECT t0.REPORT_COMMENTS 
FROM dwhsd001.LogischRapport t0 
WHERE t0.rapportnr = ? AND t0.rapporttype = ? 
[params=(long) 1473, (String) RAP]
```

**Can anyone point out why I might be seeing this behavior and how I can avoid it?**

Its not a LAZY loading problem as I've specifically tested that case. I don't see any other reason why OpenJPA decides to retrieve this one column using separate statements.

### Update 1

Interesting addition: as soon as I remove the `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` attribute from the `@OneToMany` annotation described above I start seeing the **exact same behavior** for the relationship as I've been getting for the `REPORT_COMMENTS` column. This means I'm also getting separate `SELECT` statements for retrieving the entity relationship **on top of the seperate selects for the column** thereby further degrading performance.

In other words I'm then also getting tons of these:

```
SELECT t0.isotaalcode, t0.rapportnr, t0.rapporttype, 
    t0.FUNCDESC_MODIFIED_BY, t0.FUNCDESC_MODIFIED_DATE, 
    t0.FUNCTIONAL_DESCRIPTION, t0.omschrijving, t0.titel 
FROM dwhsd001.Raptaalmetadata t0 
WHERE t0.rapportnr = ? AND t0.rapporttype = ?
```